# IPhone application in HTML 5

Tags: iphone, html

I have got a assignment to develop a IPhone application in HTML 5 & I really don't have any idea from where I have to start.
Please let me know which editor I have to use to develop IPhone application in HTML 5. 
also, as I am a pure .NET developer, what other skills I need to write the program in HTML 5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When they say develop an iPhone application in HTML 5, what they are really saying is develop a web application that fits in the dimensions of an iPhone. So you do not need to know any Apple centric technologies. You can use your ASP.NET/HTML/Javascript/CSS skills.

If you need any rich interactions in your app, you will then need to use HTML 5 with the canvas element. I recommend using the library [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) which makes working with the canvas element much easier.

Comment: Just another small question here, all the answer given to me are absolute fit to my requirement. I am unable to mark all of them as answer. How can I mark them as answer or I have to choose only one among them ?

Comment: Glad you were able to find the responses useful. Unfortunately this site only allows you to select one answer. I have been in the same situation and have just selected my favorite answer and up-voted the others.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 isn't that different from HTML. For a great resource, check out Apple's developer site. Here's the section on Safari: http://developer.apple.com/safari/.

In terms of what editor you should use: You can use whatever editor you want! Notepad for Windows works fine ;) On the Mac, I prefer [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) or [Textwranger](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/). Dashcode will work too! In order to write HTML5, you just need to know HTML, CSS and Javascript (jQuery would help too).

And, what's more, since this is just HTML, don't forget you can test it in the browser on your desktop before you test on the iPhone or the iPhone Simulator (included in Xcode). I'd recommend testing in Safari first and Google Chrome second.

Good luck and welcome to the wonderful world of HTML5 and iPhone development!

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know which editor I have to use to develop IPhone application in HTML 5.

Any you like. I usually go to Komodo Edit.

> What other skills I need to write the program in HTML 5.

HTML, JavaScript and DOM are key, along with the new JS APIs introduced in the HTML 5 Drafts. CSS is all but essential and you'll probably want some skill at graphics editing. SQL will be useful if you want to use a database.